# How to get the latest date of entry for each user in Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

If I make a `GROUP BY auth_user.id` it gives me the list. If the users who are grouped has more than one rows I get the date when the user filled my form first time. If I order it by date (`DESC`), it orders it by the date when of the first time he filled the form.

How can I get the date of the last time when he filled the form and the users are grouped? Now I'm here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM answers
ORDER BY date DESC
```

It gives all the entries of all users and every dates descending. It's okay.

```
SELECT * 
FROM answers
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Now it gives grouped data but with the first date of every users. How can I get the last date if grouped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max(date)` to get the most recent date for each user.

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  MAX(date)
FROM answers
GROUP BY user_id,
ORDER BY date DESC;
```